# how to remove existing data from a control in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

i have a code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
  $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
});
});
</script>
<body>
 <ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
 </ol>
 <button id="btn2">Append list item</button>
```

here each button click "Appended item" is appended in **li** tag.Likewise how can i remove already exist  '**li**' tags and add "Appened item" '**li**' tag

Answer (score 1):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("ol").html("<li>Appended item</li>");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pnfhg/)

Note: This will remove all `li`s in the ul and keep only the new one

Answer (score 0):

use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$("ol li").remove();
```

or
use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$("ol").empty();
```